# How to retrieve logging config in Azure Storage Blob, Queue and Table Service with Python Azure SDK

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-storage-queues

Can someone guide me to retrieve logging information of Storage Queue Service similar to the part I have circled in red as instructed in this article?

**Image:**

[image]

Article link: https://www.trendmicro.com/cloudoneconformity/knowledge-base/azure/StorageAccounts/storage-logging-for-queue-service.html

I use Python Azure SDK to do this

Thank you !

I want to check if the Read-Write-Delete actions are Enabled or Not, but currently, I have not found any similar documentation from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone guide me to retrieve logging information of Storage Queue Service similar to the part I have circled in red as instructed in this article?

You can use the below code to retrieve logging information of Storage Queue Service using Azure Python SDK.

You need to install the **[azure-storage-queue](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-queue/)** package in your environment.

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.queue import QueueServiceClient

connection_string = "xxxx"
queue_service_client = QueueServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

service_properties = queue_service_client.get_service_properties()
analytics_logging = service_properties.get("analytics_logging")
print(analytics_logging)
```

The above code is using the **`Azure Storage Queue Python SDK`** to connect to an Azure Storage account using the connection string. It then creates a **`QueueServiceClient`** object using the connection string and retrieves the service properties of the queue service. Finally, it retrieves the analytics logging setting from the service properties.

**Output:**

```
{'version': '1.0', 'delete': False, 'read': False, 'write': False, 'retention_policy': <azure.storage.queue._models.RetentionPolicy object at 0x000002288F89A9D0>}
```

[image]

Similarly, you can use the **[azure-storage-blob](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/)** and **[azure-storage-table](https://pypi.org/project/azure-data-tables/)**  package for retrieve logging information of Azure storage Blob, Table service using Azure Python SDK.